Error while Deploying my NextJs Application | build is without Error but Failed to compile while deployment
Vercel Deployment Build Log
Build Summary in local host
I have tried changing the alias @/components/Navbar.tsx path to relative path but did not worked for me.
Also tried changing NavBar.tsx to Navbar.tsx.
Nothing solve the issue.
